# Is there any benefit to wrapping a bufio.Scanner's reader in a bufio.Reader?

Tags: parsing, go, buffer

I'm using `bufio.Scanner`, and I'm not sure if I should be giving it a reader wrapped by `bufio.Reader`.

I.e., where `f` is an `os.File`, should I:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
```

or

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bufio.NewReader(f))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `scan.go` source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go) it doesn't look like you need to pass it a `*bufio.Reader`: it has its own buffer, defaulting to 4K as `bufio.Reader`'s buffers do.

```
// NewScanner returns a new Scanner to read from r.
// The split function defaults to ScanLines.
func NewScanner(r io.Reader) *Scanner {
    return &Scanner{
        r:            r,
        split:        ScanLines,
        maxTokenSize: MaxScanTokenSize,
        buf:          make([]byte, 4096), // Plausible starting size; needn't be large.
    }
}
```